# Python: Cannot open file for reading

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to run a program (word_count.py) on a text file from the command line in windows.
However, it throws and exception for reading the file. Can someone tell me why?

Here is the py file:

```
import sys
import re
import string

def Usage():
print "Usage:word_count.py [doc1] [doc2] ... [docN]"

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
Usage()
sys.exit()

for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        with open(fn) as textf:
        word_map = {}
        total_cnt = 0

        # reads one line at a time
        for line in textf:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue

            tempwords = line.split()

            for w in tempwords:
                w = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', w)
                if w:
                    if w.lower() in word_map:
                        word_map[w.lower()] += 1
                    else:
                        word_map[w.lower()] = 1
                    total_cnt += 1
        print fn+' ------ total word count: '+str(total_cnt)

    output_f_name = 'word_count_'+fn
    with open(output_f_name, 'wb') as output:
        for ele in sorted(word_map.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
            output.write('{}   {}\n'.format(str(ele[1]).rjust(6), ele[0].ljust(2)))
     except IOError:
        print 'Cannot open file %s for reading' % fn
        exit(1)
```

Both the .py file and .txt file are located on my desktop and I am running the program from the command line using:

c:\Users\Me\Desktop> word_count.py [file.txt]

Comment: can you give more details? the error log?

Comment: (your indentation is wrong, please correct it)

Comment: Shouldn't your command be `python word_count.py file.txt`? (I'm assuming `python` is in `%PATH%`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you are literally surrounding the file name with square brackets on the command line, that would likely be the problem. Even though the arguments are treated as a list, it's inferred and you just separate list items by having spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put square brackets around the file name on the command line.

Use this instead:

```
word_count.py file.txt
```

The square brackets are usually used to indicate an argument is optional, in usage strings.

Comment: Running with or without the brackets does not affect the outcome. I still get thrown the exception "Cannot open file.txt for reading."

Comment: @user1781516 Can you also print the exception's message? (`except IOError, e: print "...", e`)